# eclipse run maven project : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, maven, tomcat

when i try to run my maven project in eclispe, i meet this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base E:\calypso-dev-package\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\BookSys does not exist or is not a readable directory
at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4320)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4489)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

Can someone give me some help?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your Eclipse workspace got corrupt. You need to fix your workspace to get it working again. To do it :

1. Close Eclipse
2. Delete the `.metadata` folder under `E:\calypso-dev-package\workspace\`
3. Open Eclipse
4. Reimport your projects.

Comment: Thanks. There is no exception now.

Comment: Thanks Pradeep Pati. A year after you saved me much time.